# How to disable a particular button/link in a webview in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development. Created a simple application with a webview. Webview loads a url. Now I want to disable only one button from the website. How can I do that using the class name of the button?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't. if you decided to make a web GUI then handle actions in "web" way (JS?). if you want to handle natively clicks and other actions (different gestures, scroll, etc.) then make native GUI with XML. making such hybrid as you decribed, [while possible e.g. using JS interface for making communication web<->native sides](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript), is waste of time and resources (for handling whole GUI, especially so basic actions like clicks or enablind/disabling items)

Comment: it is possible and should be made with linked in answer JS interface for dynamic use. another, very not pro, way is to download your site as `String` (with any way), then modify HTML code on-the-fly with adding disabled state to found HTML id. if this is one and only action then maybe make two website url or handle some param send with any method like `POST` or in header (well, for `WebView` you can't manage all headers, but you can change `useragent`)